# сращивание теней между двумя div

Tags: html, css

[image: img] 
Есть макет, на фотографии его часть. Не знаю как реализовать сращивание теней показанное на фото. Элементы с выбором являются отдельной секцией, картинка и текст ниже - другой секцией. Использовать js нельзя.

Comment: А фото где?????

Comment: должно было появиться

Answer (score 2):

Как например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1rem 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

ul li {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

ul .active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

ul .active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="active">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.Решил проблему использованием рамки и немного кастылей.